# Being to foolish to correctly implement a module library into my project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-module

I recently started developing my really first Android Project using Android Studio 3.1.2.

Therefore I implemented a module library into my app, by cloning it from github, imported it as module library and added a dependency via right-click on app > module settings, switch to dependency tab, hit the +, select imported_module.

Additionally I checked my build.gradle(Module:app), if the dependency has been added correctly, there this line appeared:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':imported_module')
}
```

Also in the settings.gradle file it says:

```
include ':app', ':imported_module'
```

Now if I want to access features of imported_module any of them can't be resolved. I browsed the official and the common forums for hours to find the one step I obviously missed but wasn't smart enough to find the solution.

Synching the project with gradle files didn't cause any visible effects

What do I still have to do to be able to use all the fancy stuff fro imported_module inside my app? Do I have to import it in a certain way?
Or do I have to modify my AndroidManifest of my app somehow? Thanks in forward!

EDIT: could it be that my app and imported_module obviously have different package names? The Project File Tree says com.domain.example.my_app for the app and com.domain.example.imported_module for imported_module. Do I have to squeeze the one into the other?

Comment: did you sync with gradle?

Comment: @TimCastelijns do you mean syncing the project with gradle files? Several times. Oddly I can't open the code package of the java directory of imported_module. Could it be that the library is corrupted?

Comment: try deleting `~/.gradle/caches` and sync again

Comment: @TimCastelijns how do I do this properly?

Comment: navigate to the folder and delete it

Comment: @TimCastelijns *sighs* can't even find this file, i should continue tomorrow i guess ^^

Comment: I kinda fixed it, just added a remote dependency in my gradle, i will close this issue for now

Answer (score 1):

It could have been much easier, if you had mentioned what exactly you want to access in main app. May be access specifier of the member in your imported_module is private.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda worked around the whole thing, by just adding a remote dependency in my build.gradle file of a new project, pasted my java classes and my res into this new project, synched it and now it runs. Nevertheless thanks for thy help!

Answer (score -1):

That should be really all. Be sure to sync your project with Gradle files (File - Sync Project with Gradle Files).

Comment: *That should be really all* - well, obviously not. This is hardly an answer